# Withdrawing a doctoral application and re-applying before deadline

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I applied for a doctorate programme and got a confirmation email that it was successfully submitted. Later, I realised I omitted some important information in my application that I need to add.

If I am still within the application deadline, can I ask for a withdrawal of my application and then re-apply before the deadline date?

Comment: Why not ask, instead, if you can supplement the original information? It is probably less disruptive. Or, at least, ask them how it is best to proceed.

Comment: If the information was important to them, then they should have followed up with you. The fact they accepted it means it probably isn’t that important. But like @Buffy said, ask if you can make a variation (like with ethics applications) rather than withdraw.

Comment: @Earlien I doubt any human has seen their application yet. The OP says the admitted important information, not required.

Comment: @AzorAhai Fair point, but my advice would be the same - ask if there is any way to edit the application rather than withdraw. I would only submit again if they advised withdrawing and making a new submission.

Comment: @Earlien Yes, fair.